# Reference a foreign key and Add check constraint for column in parent table

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can I Add to the Table `BusinessCategories` a check that the column `IsBusinessCategory` value is 'true' for the related `Categories.ID`?

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Categories](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ParentID] [int] NULL,
    [DisplayNameHe] [nvarchar](400) NOT NULL,
    [DisplayNameEn] [nvarchar](400) NOT NULL,
    [DisplayNameEs] [nvarchar](400) NOT NULL,
    [CreateDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [Status] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [IsBusinessCategory] [bit] NULL
)



CREATE TABLE [dbo].[BusinessCategories](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    [BusinessCategoryID] [INT] NOT NULL REFERENCES Categories(ID) -- Need to check that is 
     businessCategory ==1
    [BusinessID] [INT] NOT NULL REFERENCES Business(ID)
)
```

The goal is to be able to insert to the column **BusinessCategoryID** only values from **Categories** table that has **IsBusinessCategory == true**.

Comment: @Sami that's not the issue, the question is how to add a check for the column to have a value of 1?

Comment: @Sami I need to check that `IsBusinessCategory = 1`

Comment: You can create an scalar function to make that validation, but is not recommended since an update in your categories table won't be checked again

Comment: Before the record is inserted into the BusinessCategories table, write an if exists code to see the particular BusinessCategoryID has the corresponding IsBusinessCategory flag as true.

Comment: Is there any possibility that a `Category` that has `IsBusinessCategory=1` will one day get changed to `0`?    And if that happens, do you want the CHECK to prevent it, or what?

Comment: Foreign keys do not support additional checks or filters. Either duplicate the `IsBusinessCategory` column in `BusinessCategories` and make (`BusinessCategoryID, IsBusinessCategory`) a compound foreign key (complete with check on `IsBusinessCategory`), or split `Categories` into `BusinessCategories` and `NonBusinessCategories` (and reintroduce it as a view that combines both tables, for example).

Comment: @TabAlleman That's what I want, and for inserting to the `BusinessCategories` table I want to first check that is has a value = `1`

Comment: The fact that you are struggling so much with a foreign key is a clear sign that you need to rework your architecture a bit.

Answer (score 2):

I don't recommend that kind of solution, that should be done in the application's business layer

In SQL side there is a tricky way, not optimal, but doable...

First create an scalar function that returns the isBusinessCategory value of the selected category

```
CREATE FUNCTION fn_isBusinessCategory (@CatID INT) RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN (SELECT isBusinessCategory FROM Categories WHERE CategoryID = @CatID)
END
GO
```

Create another scalar function that returns 1 if a given category is referenced in BusinessCategories

```
CREATE FUNCTION fn_isBusinessCategoryValid (@CatID INT, @isBusinessCat BIT) RETURNS BIT
AS
BEGIN
    IF @isBusinessCat = 1
        RETURN 1
    ELSE IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM BusinessCategories WHERE CategoryID = @CatID)
        RETURN 0
    ELSE
        RETURN 1
END
GO
```

Add the following constraints

Step 1 Foreign key to validate integrity between two tables

```
ALTER TABLE BusinessCategories ADD CONSTRAINT FK_BusinessCategory 
FOREIGN KEY (CategoryID) 
REFERENCES Categories (CategoryID)
```

Step 2 Check constraint to validate that category is_businessCategory

```
ALTER TABLE BusinessCategories ADD CONSTRAINT ck_BusinessCategory 
CHECK (dbo.fn_isBusinessCategory(CategoryID) = 1)
```

Step 3 Check constraint to prevent a category to be changed as non businessCategory when is used

```
ALTER TABLE Categories ADD CONSTRAINT ck_Category_isBusinessCategory 
CHECK (dbo.fn_isBusinessCategoryValid(CategoryID, isBusinessCategory) = 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

> The goal is to be able to insert to the column BusinessCategoryID only
>   values from Categories table that has IsBusinessCategory == true.

You can do this much by writing a UDF that takes `BusinessCategoryID` as a parameter and queries the Categories table to get the value of `IsBusinessCategory`.    The CHECK constraint would simply test whether the returned value of the parameter is true or false.

Be warned however, that this constraint will only be checked when you add rows to the `BusinessCategories` table.   If someone changes the value of `IsBusinessCategory` in the `Categories` table, the CHECK constraint will not catch it.   You would need to put a separate constraint on the `Categories` table to catch that.